# php7 doesn't seems to be parsing files

Tags: apache2, lamp, php7

I've a server with ubuntu 14. Previously I had apache2, PHP 5 and MySQL installed and it was working pretty well, but I had to install PHP7+PThreads extension, so I unninstalled the previous version (PHP 5). For what I see, PHP is installed and running in the system, I typed `php -v` and I get this:

```
PHP 7.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2016 22:13:21) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Now, when I go to `MyIPAddress/MyPage` Apache shows me the PHP code of the page, is like PHP is not related with apache2. I even made `service apache2 restart`

For other side, I went to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and there's nothing related with PHP, neither in `mods-available` so what should I check? Or where am I wrong?
I'm not very good at linux shell. Thanks!

Comment: I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and installed php7
in terminal i can see the apache and php installed but still
Having same problem :(

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the Apache module installed:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

I had the same problem for a while, but just fixed installing that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use command `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache` to see
the list of installed apache service.

If you see the `libapache2-mod-php7.0` is missing 
then use following command to list all available the php7.0 service

```
 sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

Now install required services

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json
```

Now restart the apache `sudo service apache2 restart`